# Strange freezing when using UITextField

Tags: swift, crash, uitextfield

I have `UITableViewController` that segues to another `tvc`. In this `vc`, the first `cell` has a `UITextField`.

Firstly, if I go on the `storyboard` and set a `placeholder text` for the `UITextField`, when I then try to segue to the `vc` with the `textfield`, the app freezes. However, Xcode doesn't report any crashes or errors. The app is simply blocked to the user.
What's interesting is that although the app is frozen, the segue still occurs, since if I print something from `viewDidLoad` it shows up on the console.

Something similar happens if I disable the `placeholder text`. If keep typing into the `textfield`, the app eventually freezes.

I have not seen this behavior previously when dealing with `UITextFields`. How can I fix this and why is it occurring?

I'm running XCode 7.2.

Comment: Please share the crashes. Without pertinent information I cannot even begin to help you. Also xcode 7.2 is relatively old... 9 is out already.

Comment: @Colton there are no crashes. The app just freezes.

Comment: Your question says crashes

Comment: What I mean is there are no crashes reported by XCode, I will rephrase question.

Comment: try xcode 9 btw

Comment: @Colton, would have to update operating system, mac is relatively old.

Comment: Use Xcode to pause the app and enter the debugger during the freeze.  Examine what's happening on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Erase all content and settings" in the simulator.

This is how to do it on XCode 11.5

[image: XCode 11.5]